# Difference between grouped sums for two different dates in multi-index pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-index`DataFrame` grouped by three columns (`date`, `Ticker`, `Security Description`):

```
df.groupby(['date','Ticker', 'Security Description']).sum()
```

I would next like to calculate the differences between say today (2020-01-02 in the example) and yesterday *or if yesterday is missing, the closest date prior to yesterday where there is data* for both tickers and security description.

Here is the sample data I am working with:

```
df = {'transactionID': {0: 5, 1: 7, 2: 5, 3: 7, 4: 6, 5: 6},
 'date': {0: '1/1/2020',
  1: '1/1/2020',
  2: '1/2/2020',
  3: '1/2/2020',
  4: '12/31/2019',
  5: '1/2/2020'},
 'Dollar Gain': {0: 500, 1: 100, 2: -200, 3: -200, 4: -50, 5: 50},
 'Date': {0: '4/24/2018',
  1: '4/24/2018',
  2: '4/24/2018',
  3: '4/24/2018',
  4: '5/24/2019',
  5: '5/24/2019'},
 'Notional': {0: 5, 1: 10, 2: 5, 3: 10, 4: 1, 5: -1},
 'Ticker': {0: 'AAPL', 1: 'MCD', 2: 'AAPL', 3: 'MCD', 4: 'SBUX', 5: 'SBUX'},
 'Security Description': {0: 'AAPL Equity',
  1: 'MCD Equity',
  2: 'AAPL Equity',
  3: 'MCD Equity',
  4: 'SBUX Equity',
  5: 'SBUX Equity'},
 'Price': {0: 100.0, 1: 80.0, 2: 105.5, 3: 105.5, 4: 80.0, 5: 80.0}}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df.set_index('date', 'Ticker')
df.groupby(['date','Ticker', 'Security Description']).sum()
```

[image: df]

Below is my desired output for tickers.

- 1/2/2020 AAPL ticker Dollar Gains is -200. 1/1/2020 AAPL ticker Dollar gains was 500. The difference is then -700.
- For SBUX, since there is no entry on 1/1/2020 the value from 12/31/2019 (the closest date prior to 1/1/2020) is used, so 50-(-50)=100.

[image: desired-output]

**EDIT**

In addition to being able to handle yesterday (the previous observation), how would you generalize the solution to work for Month to Date, Year to Date, and between any two custom dates?

Answer (score 2):

Fix your code with `diff`

```
g=df.groupby(['date','Ticker', 'Security Description']).sum()
ydf=g.groupby(level=1).apply(lambda x : x.diff().sum())
Out[35]: 
        transactionID  Dollar Gain  Notional  Price
Ticker                                             
AAPL              0.0       -700.0       0.0    5.5
MCD               0.0       -300.0       0.0   25.5
SBUX              0.0       -100.0       2.0    0.0
```

Comment: This doesn't work. SBUX should be 100 Dollar Gain and -2 notional.

Comment: This also does not work because there may be multiple securities on the same date for a single ticker. There may be "AAPL Debt" Security Description that shares the same ticker as "AAPL Equity".

Comment: @cpage sort your date first ~:-)

Comment: Sorting addresses the first comment but not the second.

Comment: `df.groupby(['date','Ticker', 'Security Description']).sum().groupby(['Ticker', 'Security Description']).apply(lambda x: x.diff().sum())` seems to address the second comment.

Comment: @cpagec `g.groupby(level=[1,2]).apply(lambda x : x.diff().sum())`

Comment: Great that works. See EDIT to question regarding generalizing beyond just handling yesterday.